# Get (remote) node name(-space) when receiving a message

Tags: ros-kinetic, namespace, messages, node, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

when I subscribe to a topic, is there a way to get the name / namespace of the publishing node on reception of a message?

I know about `ros::this_node::getName()` and the like [[Ref]](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1this__node.html) but that only yields the name/-space of the *current* node. For example, assume I (manually) subscribe to `/rosout` and I am receiving a message send from the node `/foo/bar/node1`. Is there a way to get this information (`/foo/bar/node1`) in the callback?

Please note that I prefer a way to do this in **roscpp**.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Since I am dealing with custom messages here, I've simply added the namespace of the sender to my message definition. However, I thought there's probably some smarter way to do this (and I was hoping that the sender is already contained somewhere in the received message data).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240362/get-(remote)-node-name(-space)-when-receiving-a-message/) by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There aren't a lot of good reasons for wanting to do this, because it breaks the anonymity of the **Anonymous** publish/subscribe data flow model. It can be useful for debugging, but building functional logic that depends on the publisher name it is not usually a good idea.

Caveats aside, you can access the publisher name by subscribing to the `MessageEvent<msgtype>` object (templated on your actual message type), which contains additional metadata in addition to the message data. Have a look at the [MessageEvent subsection](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D) of the ROSCPP Publishers and Subscribers page for the details.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2016-07-26**:
Thanks for your answer, good point! What I am considering is: given a **global** topic `/ping`, all my robots (/nodes) send a regular msg to that topic. This way, all robots are able to **detect other active robots** by subscribing to `/ping`. This "detection" is somehow necessary as there comes ...

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2016-07-26**:
... a point where two (or more) robots need to interact (/communicate) with each other.

To start communication, a node needs to know the namespace which I add to all msgs send to `/ping`. IMHO, This **retains anonymity until** two nodes start (bidirectional) communication. What do you think about this?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-26**:
I like your approach because it keeps the anonymity in the pub/sub model, and because it explicitly communicates the namespaces to be used for future communication, instead of trying to infer the namespace from the node name.

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2016-07-26**:
Thanks, then I'll stick to that design. ;-)